# Is this sentence grammatically correct? (I want to stress ***how grateful I am for giving me*** this opportunity...)

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

I came across this sentence online, and am wondering if it's grammatically right.

> First of all, I want to stress **how grateful I am for giving me** this opportunity to interview for this position.

Since the subject of the sentence is "I", and the person the speaker is thanking to is a different person(interviewer), shouldn't it be something like what's below?

> I want to stress **how grateful I am for you to give me** this opportunity to interview for this position.

I know I can choose to go as simple as "I am grateful to have this opportunity." but wasn't exactly sure which is grammatically right (or wrong) in these specific sentences.

Comment: Yes - it's just a slip. They should have said **how grateful to you I am** or **how grateful I am for being given...**

Comment: @KateBunting thank you, and the one I wrote "how grateful I am for you to give me" isn't natural? Just wanted to make it clear...

Comment: You are grateful _to_ someone _for_ what they give you/do for you - and, yes, the participle _giving_ is required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1

> First of all, I want to stress how grateful I am for giving me this opportunity to interview for this position.

2

> I want to stress how grateful I am for you to give me this opportunity to interview for this position.

There is a similar example for *grateful* in [CambridgeDictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grateful)

> showing or expressing thank, especially to another person:
>
> I'm so grateful (**to** you) **for** all that you've done.

We could consider the suggestions shown in brackets:

> I want to stress how grateful I am [to you] for giving me this opportunity to interview for this position.

> I want to stress how grateful I am for [being given] this opportunity to interview for this position.

The phrase *First of all* is optional.

Answer (score 1):

grateful  someone

grateful  something

It should have been 'How grateful I am  you...